# In Api URL how to Increment Page NUmber in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

i amnot getting in Django Pease help me .. In my Api request i have particular page number i amnot able to understand how to increment that page number by dynamically please help in this

#URL
base_url = 'https://api.kayzen.io/v1/reports/336960/report_results?end_date={}&page=1&per_page=25&sort_direction=desc&start_date={}'.format(
today,today)

In this URL page is their that number should increment not other number.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide some more info to get the help you need. If youre paginating the queryset manually, then simply pass the page number you need to the paginator.
In classbased views pagination is handled for you but you can override that as well.

```
def posts(request):
   page_num = request.Get.get('page', 1) #get page num from request
   pages = Paginator(queryset, num_items_per_page) # paginate queryset/iterable 

   #to get a page
   page_2 = pages.page(2)
   page.object_list  # prints out curr objects.
```

you can pass the page to your template to render the objects in the page

this will help out
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#the-paginator-class
you may read more here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/paginator/#paginator-class

Comment: Hi not this type pagination i dnot want in api url request how to call after 1 hours it should change page number like that type i want  How i have add my code i amnot understanding